# Does the Dart Aqueduct server have a string validator built in?

Tags: string, validation, dart, aqueduct

I'm using the [string_validator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/string_validator) package that I forked from an older unmaintained package. I was wondering if [Aqueduct](https://aqueduct.io/) has some sort of string validation already built in? If if does, I couldn't find it. I'd like to validate an email address and add password constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are a handful of built in validators that you annotate database fields with. You can also create new validators that use methods from the package you shared. See http://aqueduct.io/docs/db/validations/